# Returning pointer freed inside function

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

This doesn't *seem* to have any problems running but I'm thinking when it returns, `buff` might automagically be freed which would in turn free `*string` and cause problems the next time I allocate and that memory gets overwritten (or worse, etc etc). I don't want to test by trial and error because I may simply have been lucky in my tests so far. Am I doing this wrong?

```
void strCat1000(char *concatDest, char *format, ...)
{
  char buff[1000];

  va_list arg_ptr;
  va_start(arg_ptr, format);

  vsnprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, arg_ptr);

  va_end(arg_ptr);

  free(concatDest);
  concatDest=buff;
}
```

More concisely, is concatDest pointing to freed memory after this function returns?

Comment: The creator should be the destroyed. Consider if `concatDest` is on the stack?!

Comment: Oops - that sounded a bit religious - did not mean it to be that way

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to concatenate several strings and put them in concatDest. I want to make it so it still works if I want to store result in one of the strings I'm concatenating too though.

Comment: In summary... This function is a disaster and it would be better to declare it as `char* strCat1000(char *format, ...)` and not do any free-ing inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
concatDest=buff;
}
```

This last statement will not change the observable behavior of the program and is very likely to be just optimized out by any decent compiler.

Remember C passes arguments by value and you are not modifying the original pointer but a local copy in your function.

Comment: @AppFzx if you want to modify the original pointer yes, but you cannot pass `buffer`. `buffer` object has automatic storage duration and will be destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: And calling it something like `strCat1000(&logText, "log this %s, %s, %s","stuff1","stuff2","stuff3")`?

Comment: @AppFzx yes, but again returning `buff` is wrong as it will be destroyed. Moreover you `free` inside your function is bad design, it would be better to `free` in the same scope as you `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
concatDest=buff;
```

Not a good idea because when the function returns, all its `local variables are destroyed`. So if you try to access data (outside this function) that was stored in `buff` whose address was assigned to `concatDest`, you will Segmentationf fault

Answer (score 0):

You should be,

- taking a length parameter
- passing concatDest to vsnprintf

..but then you're just left with snprintf

buff is allocated on the stack, and assigning concatDest to its address won't work since the memory it points to goes away as soon as the stack is popped (when you return).

More concisely: Yes, the memory has been freed. It may not have been overwritten (so it might appear to work for a little bit) but it will be very soon.

Answer (score 0):

`buff` is a local variable, so it is invalid (popped off the stack) when the function returns.  But then so is `concatDest`, so there's no problem -- you just have a local variable that points at a local variable and both go away at the same time.

Now what you might be thinking of is if you call this function like:

```
strCat1000(string, "some format", some other args);
```

but in this case, `string` is not affected by changes to `concatDest` in the function -- arguments are passed by value in C.  Of course, this means that your function has no effect
at all -- it prints into a temp buffer and then destroys that buffer, but it has no effect on
`string` or `*string` in the process.